# Can M Project be used to create Mobile Web Applications even without native compilation?

Tags: html, node.js, jquery-mobile, javascript-framework

Im looking for an HTML 5 / Mobile Web Application framework and came across M Project.  Im interested to dive into the framework but before I commit my time Id first like to know if M Project is advisable for Mobile Web App which will not be natively compiled?  Is it even meant to be used for non natively compiled mobile web apps?
Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

The platform will work fine for non-native apps. According to the site (http://www.the-m-project.org/), the framework code is only 66Kb.